# Vue.js 'mounted' is not waiting for private function to return

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Full disclosure, I'm a .NET/C# dev and a complete novice when it comes to Javascript. This language is breaking my brain.

I'm trying to get the broswer's location to feed to a map component that is being created in [`mounted`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted) as part of the vuejs options lifecycle. It correctly calls the private function, but `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns AFTER `mounted` finishes, so the map is initialized to a position of 0,0 (my defaults) instead of the correct long/lat. I suspect something should be using async/await but I can't figure out where or how to get that to work, no matter what I've tried. My code is below.

The private function:

```js
function calculateBrowserLocation() {
let location = {
  longitude: 0,
  latitude: 0
}

if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    console.log(`Inside navigator.getCurrentPosition\nlongitude: ${position.coords.longitude}\nlatitude: ${position.coords.longitude}`)
    location.longitude = position.coords.longitude
    location.latitude = position.coords.latitude      
  })
}    

console.log(`Inside GetBrowserLocation\nlongitude: ${location.longitude}\nlatitude: ${location.longitude}`)

return location  }
```

The export default section:

```js
export default {
setup() {    
  let browserLocation = {
    longitude: 0,
    latitude: 0
  }
  let bearing = 0
  let pitch = 0
  let zoom = 10

  return { browserLocation, bearing, pitch, zoom } 
},

mounted() {
  console.log(`Before GetBrowserLocation\nlongitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}\nlatitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}`)

  this.browserLocation = calculateBrowserLocation()

  console.log(`After GetBrowserLocation\nlongitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}\nlatitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}`)

  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: this.$refs.mapContainer,
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
    center: [this.browserLocation.longitude, this.browserLocation.latitude],
    bearing: this.bearing,
    pitch: this.pitch,
    zoom: this.zoom
  })

  console.log(`After map creation\nlongitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}\nlatitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}`)
},

unmounted() {
  this.map.remove()
  this. Map = null
}}
```

The output of all those `console.log` statements, which demonstrates the timing issues of all of this looks like:

[image]

I suspect it's something very simple, as these things often are, but I haven't been able to Google/SO/Reddit my way out of it.

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` gets the position asynchronously, so that's why your code doesn't wait for the result

Comment: You probably want something like [this](https://pastebin.com/nrw8YLTk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Api getCurrentPosition is Asynchronous behavior,if you want get its value synchronously just using Promise, async, and await to solve this.

```js
function calculateBrowserLocation() {
  return new Promise(res => {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(`Inside navigator.getCurrentPosition\nlongitude:${position.coords.longitude}\nlatitude: ${position.coords.longitude}`)
        res(position.coords)
      })
    } else {
      res({
        longitude: 0,
        latitude: 0
      })
    }
  })
}
async mounted() {
  console.log(`Before GetBrowserLocation\nlongitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}\nlatitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}`)

  this.browserLocation = await calculateBrowserLocation()

  console.log(`After GetBrowserLocation\nlongitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}\nlatitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}`)

  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: this.$refs.mapContainer,
    style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
    center: [this.browserLocation.longitude, this.browserLocation.latitude],
    bearing: this.bearing,
    pitch: this.pitch,
    zoom: this.zoom
  })

  console.log(`After map creation\nlongitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}\nlatitude: ${this.browserLocation.longitude}`)
}
```